# Bash doesn't end the loop despite pipeline is broken

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop, stream, pipeline

The simple script:

```
while [ 1 ]; do
    cat pattern_file
done | socat - /dev/ttyS0
```

It makes a stream, looped pattern included in the file and sends it into the serial port via socat. The script also allows to read data back from the serial port.
Unfortunately when socat ends (eg. killed) the loop hangs forever without any error message.
I want to avoid:

- pts
- more scripts than one
- reopening the serial port every pattern_file

Comment: What is the purpose of the while loop here... Why not cat directly to the pipe?

Comment: As I wrote: it makes looped stream according to pattern in the file. If I use pipe directly socat will reopen the port every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that you are running into is that, under `bash` (other may shells differ), a pipeline terminates only after *all* commands in the pipeline are finished.

One solution is to use:

```
while [ 1 ]; do
    cat pattern_file || break
done | socat - /dev/ttyS0
```

If `socat` terminates, then the `cat` command will fail when it runs.  However, the mere failure of a command in a loop does not cause the loop to terminate.  By adding the `break` command, we can assure that, if the `cat` fails, then the loop will terminate.

Another solution is to avoid pipelines altogether and use *process substitution*:

```
socat - /dev/ttyS0 < <(while true; do cat pattern_file; done)
```

#### Documentation

The problematic pipeline behavior is documented in `man bash`:

> The shell waits for all commands in the pipeline to terminate before returning a value.

Comment: Going a little deeper, when `socat` ends, its end of the pipe is closed, and any attempt to write to the pipe causes the writer (in this case `cat`) to receive a `SIGPIPE` signal. The `while` command itself, since it never actually writes to the pipe (it just passes its open file handle to `cat`), has no idea that the other end is closed. Thus, only `cat` ever (repeatedly) gets `SIGPIPE` and exits.